# Issue in Google Sheets with Query Function leaving ghost copies when output is shortened

Tags: sql, google-sheets

[Ghost Copy with Highlights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDUzq.png)I am currently having an issue with what appears to be the very coding of the Query Function in Google Sheets. The offending error is occurring under the following circumstances. (Google and Stack Overflow have been combed for solutions already; either I don't know the proper language to find a solution or I am encountering an exceptionally rare error, in either case I need help.)

I have a Query Function displaying only active jobs on a page that is purely for display, such that the most urgent job is always at the top. The issue comes in when a job on the referenced page is marked as finished; at this point, it successfully disappears from the display page, but since the list is shortened, as all the jobs below it jump up to take its place in the order, a ghost copy of the last job in that list remains. I can scrape by with deleting it from the display page, but it is not as automatic as I expect or would prefer. Is there a solution for this or do I need to find a way to contact google directly to report the issue?

Comment: As ever, please share a link to the sheet (or a copy of it) where the problem is happening. There is very little anyone here can do to help if we can't see the problem in context. (On the flip side, there is usually something someone CAN do to help if you allow us to see the problem in context.) As for a way to contact Google directly, you will find that extremely difficult. All forums (this one and any others like it) are attended 100% by volunteers, not by employees of Google. As such, we have no more access to developers than you do beyond the on-sheet Help > Help Sheets Improve option.

Comment: Please post a link to a view only spreadsheet. I have never seen this happen.

Comment: @JohnA, I myself have seen it happen; and it's been reported on forums by users somewhat often recently (though I don't think it's a new issue). My experience thus far has been that it often happens in relation to attempts at processing data that comes in from automated sources (e.g., forms) and can most often be circumvented by writing the formula differently (e.g., using full-column references, FILTER, etc.).

Comment: You can file a bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance so far. I have updated the original post to include an image of the spreadsheet I am working with, with the issue highlighted and the query function visible. I have reported the issue to Google, which has turned out as helpful as expected. Further assistance would be appreciated as available.